# I am getting undefined with "create" in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save a simple json data into database. When I try to save the data through Mongoose.create... I get the undefined error

App.js

```
import express from 'express';
import {router} from './config/routes';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import logger from 'morgan';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/invoice-builder');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/invoice-builder', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err) { console.log("mongoDB connected", err); }) ;

// const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test?poolSize=4';
// mongoose.createConnection(uri);

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use('/api', router);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
....
...
```

this is my controller:

```
import { Invoice } from '../models/invoice.model'

const invoices = [
    {_id: '1123', item: 'Am Prod', qty: 1, date: new Date()},
    {_id: '1124', item: 'Am Prod 1', qty: 2, date: new Date()},
    {_id: '1125', item: 'Am Prod 2', qty: 3, date: new Date()}
  ];


export default {
    findAll(req, res, next){
        // res.json(invoices);
        Invoice.find().then(invoices => res.json(invoices));
    },

    create(req, res){

        const {item, qty, date, due, tax, rate} = req.body;

        if(!item){
          return  res.status(400).json({err: 'item is required'});
        }

        if(!date){
            return  res.status(400).json({err: 'date is required'});
        }
        if(!due){
            return  res.status(400).json({err: 'due is required'});
        }

        if(!qty){
            return  res.status(400).json({err: 'qty is required'});
        }

        Invoice.create({item, qty, date, due, tax, rate})
        .then(invoice => res.json(invoice))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
    }
};
```

This is my input:

```
{
    "item" : "This is temp",
    "date" : "2019-01-01",
    "due" : "2019-03-03",
    "qty" : 1
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"
    }
}
```

Please help me find out the issue here. I have tried many of the solutions that either given in stackoverflow or other sites. But none of them have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because the Invoice variable is undefined when you call the Invoice.create function. You have to initialize Invoice first.

Something like:

```
var invoice = new Invoice();  //put it somewhere out of the create method
...
invoice.create({item, qty, date, due, tax, rate}) //use the object, not the class
```